# Log in Glitch on Log in Page

Tags: login

I have noticed a odd glitch on my CP log in page. When logging in adding my name and password I often find it takes two attempts to get into the CP ... the first loads but blanks the log in form and remains on the CP log in page.

I was wondering if anyone else had experienced this issue?

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using (Firefox?) and have you tried other browsers to see if the problem is the same?  It will do this if you have left the page for a long time before logging in as the session will be reset.

Comment: FireFox ... I think you have hit the nail on the head ... thanks.

Comment: No problem. :) With regards to the session or the browser?

Comment: It happens in Safari and Chrome as well. It's as Ian says, typically a session reset.